# How to redirect to a private Google Group?

Tags: perl, redirect, oauth, google-groups

Now, I wish to redirect to a private Google group on click of a button on my website along with search parameters. I have generated the required URL using perl. Then I made a simple redirection using . It works when the user is already logged in(using cookies). But it doesn't work if the user has not logged in. I wish to redirect to Google's login page to make sure the user has logged in and thus can access the private group. How do I do this? I read some documentation mentioning OAuth. Is this the only way?

Comment: Typically Google handles the login themselfs. A user not logged in will be redirected to their login page first.

Comment: I get a message saying "The page you requested is invalid" when the user is not signed in. But the same url works when the user is already signed in.

Comment: You should add a sample URL to your question. See the answer below on how to sign in a user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sebastian. But, I guess it is not redirecting because it is a Google Apps(organization) group. I tried using my personal google group and redirection happens automatically. Are there different group settings for free users and paid services?

Answer (score 1):

Typically Google handles the login themselfs. A user not logged in will be redirected to their login page first.
You can't use OAuth to log someone into a foreign (aka Google own) service. You could use OAuth to check if a user is logged in at all, but it's not necessary.

The [Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Google documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Google) has a pretty good description on how to setup a Google OAuth login. The [Auth::GoogleAuth](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Auth::GoogleAuth) module might do the job (with less documentation) without using Dancer, but I never tried it myself.